# In C/C++, I am trying to call different functions (explained in description) in a for loop without if-else ladder

Tags: c++, c, function

I have some APIs defined like following prototype.

```
void foo_network_call_1();
void foo_network_call_2();
void foo_network_call_3();
void foo_network_call_4();
```

and

```
void foo_parse_data_1();
void foo_parse_data_2();
void foo_parse_data_3();
void foo_parse_data_4();
```

I can make 4 calls to each type of API to get the work done. That code will not be clean etc.

I am looking for a way to call above APIs in a loop, e.g.`for` loop.

something like:

```
for (int i=1; i<5; ++i) {
   foo_network_call_##i();
   foo_parse_data_##i();
}
```

`##`
are just representing that I am appending `i` in the call. I am not aware of any calling mechanism in C/C++ which can do this.

Thank you your help.

Comment: That's a very unusual API to begin with, most nicely designed ones use actually descriptive names for their functions instead of appending numbers at the end. Also whether having these calls one after another is "not clean" is very subjective, sometimes you just have to have code like that

Comment: You could put function pointers in an array and loop through the array. You wouldn't even need the funky naming scheme then.

Comment: __C__ `!=` __C++__ `!=` __C__, They are differnet languages and demand to be treaed as such. :) Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Choose one and stick to that please.

Comment: if you remove C++ tag, then don't work with `std::function`.

Answer (score 4):

Using an array of function pointers seems like the obvious thing to do.

```
typedef void (*network_func)();
typedef void (*parse_func)();

network_func network_functions[4] = { foo_network_call_1, ... };
parse_func parse_functions[4] = { foo_parse_data_1, ... };

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    (network_functions[i])();
    (parse_functions[i])();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @john for quick response and taking my thought to function pointers. It will work. I might use C++ version of it. using std::function.

I know its not a best way to define the API but I think, it was simple way to explain, there more to it but it helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;

    auto foo_network_call_0 = [](){
        //do something...
    };
    auto foo_network_call_1 = [](){
        //do something...
    };
    auto foo_network_call_2 = [](){
        //do something...
    };
    auto foo_network_call_3 = [](){
        //do something...
    };

    auto foo_parse_data_0 = [](){
        //do something...
    };
    auto foo_parse_data_1 = [](){
        //do something...
    };
    auto foo_parse_data_2 = [](){
        //do something...
    };
    auto foo_parse_data_3 = [](){
        //do something...
    };

    std::vector<void(*)()> ary_call;
    ary_call.push_back( foo_network_call_0 );
    ary_call.push_back( foo_network_call_1 );
    ary_call.push_back( foo_network_call_2 );
    ary_call.push_back( foo_network_call_3 );

    std::vector<void(*)()> ary_data;
    ary_data.push_back( foo_parse_data_0 );
    ary_data.push_back( foo_parse_data_1 );
    ary_data.push_back( foo_parse_data_2 );
    ary_data.push_back( foo_parse_data_3 );

    for ( auto i = 0; i < 4; ++i ) {
        ary_call[i]();
        ary_data[i]();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I liked your vector approach.

Comment: Modern C++ has `std::function` for this.

Comment: Yes, you can use std::function to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If it is just a static list of functions, put them into one function then call that.

Like:

```
void foo_network() {
  void foo_network_call_1();
  void foo_network_call_2();
  void foo_network_call_3();
  void foo_network_call_4();
}
```

Comment: I was tryin to avoid this sol.

Comment: @sahn Well your question is really leaving a lot out. Like, the reason things are arranged like that and what you *actually* want to end up doing. Designing APIs might even be a better question for Software Engineering.

Comment: @sahn Why? In programming, we use functions to form abstractions over actions. That your functions _happen_ to end in numbers is pure coincidence. What happens when one of them is refactored/renamed? What happens when you get `foo_network_call_finish()`? Any other solution is relying on happenstance structure.

Comment: @ZanLynx 
I agree, I couldn't explain how exactly those APIs are designed. Actually, those APIs are not defined by me, its there in the system and I need to call then in a specific order to pass the data. Actually some repetitive data. its not the right subject to talk about it. but I was trying to get some pointers how get around it.

@GManNickG 
I need to call in order, like 
`foo_network_call_1();`
`foo_parse_data_1();`

Also, I need to pass more data different parameters to call etc.

Answer (score 1):

two answer above is correct
the only way is function pointer
i usually write this model for my codes

```
typedef void (*NetworkFunc)(void);
typedef void (*ParseFunc)(void);

const NetworkFunc NetworkFunctions[] = {
    network_func_1,
    network_func_2,
    ...
};
const NetworkFunctions_Length = sizeof(NetworkFunctions) / sizeof(NetworkFunctions[0]);

const ParseFunc ParseFunctions[] = {
    parse_func_1,
    parse_func_2,
    ...
};
const ParseFunctions_Length = sizeof(ParseFunctions) / sizeof(ParseFunctions[0]);
```

now you can use it like this

```
for (i =0; i < NetworkFunctions_Length; i++) {
    NetworkFunctions[i]();
}

for (i =0; i < ParseFunctions_Length; i++) {
    ParseFunctions[i]();
}
```

Edit:
this is alternative c++ example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

typedef function<void(void)> PrintFunc;

void Print_A(void);
void Print_B(void);
void Print_C(void);

const PrintFunc PrintFunctions[] = {
    Print_A,
    Print_B,
    Print_C,
};
const int PrintFunctions_Length = sizeof(PrintFunctions) / sizeof(PrintFunctions[0]);

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < PrintFunctions_Length; i++) {
        PrintFunctions[i]();
    }
}

void Print_A(void) {
    cout << "A\n";
}
void Print_B(void) {
    cout << "B\n";
}
void Print_C(void) {
    cout << "C\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ali for quick response. I will try this and I am sure, it will work. I might use C++ version of it. using `std::function`

Comment: yeah in c++ we have an alternative way

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use an array of function pointers and every index will be a different function, that way the i indexing will work.

```
void (*network_call_arr[])() = {foo_network_call_1, foo_network_call_2, foo_network_call_3, foo_network_call_4};

void (*parse_data_arr[]() = {foo_parse_data_1, foo_parse_data_2, foo_parse_data_3, foo_parse_data_4};
```

and just call an index to a pointer from the for loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<4; ++i) 
{
   network_call_arr[i]();
   parse_data_arr[i]();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a switch, which under optimization will probably compile to a jump table.

```
for (int i=1; i<5; ++i) 
{  switch( i)
   { case 1:
      foo_network_call_1();
      foo_parse_data_1();
     break;
     case 2:
      foo_network_call_2();
      foo_parse_data_2();
     break;
     // etc
   }
 }
```

Comment: I would say that's subjective. The function pointer approach requires the definition of two types, and if two initialized arrays that have to be kept in synch.

Comment: I mean, not cleaner then just typing `foo_network_call_1();foo_parse_data_1();foo_network_call_2();foo_parse_data_2();//etc` like he did originally

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void foo_network_call_1(int data) {
    cout <<"foo_network_call_1"<<endl;
}

void foo_network_call_2(int data) {
    cout <<"foo_network_call_2"<<endl;
}

void foo_network_call_3(int data) {
    cout <<"foo_network_call_3"<<endl;
}

void foo_network_call_4(int data) {
    cout <<"foo_network_call_4"<<endl;
}

void foo_parse_data_1(string data) {
    cout <<"foo_parse_data_1"<<endl;
}

void foo_parse_data_2(string data) {
    cout <<"foo_parse_data_2"<<endl;
}

void foo_parse_data_3(string data) {
    cout <<"foo_parse_data_3"<<endl;
}

void foo_parse_data_4(string data) {
    cout <<"foo_parse_data_4"<<endl;
}

typedef std::function<void(int)> NewWorkFunc;
typedef std::function<void(string)> ParseDatFunc;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    std::vector<NewWorkFunc>  arrNetworkCalls;
    std::vector<ParseDatFunc>  arrParsedataCalls;

    arrNetworkCalls.push_back(foo_network_call_1);
    arrNetworkCalls.push_back(foo_network_call_2);
    arrNetworkCalls.push_back(foo_network_call_3);
    arrNetworkCalls.push_back(foo_network_call_4);

    arrParsedataCalls.push_back(foo_parse_data_1);
    arrParsedataCalls.push_back(foo_parse_data_2);
    arrParsedataCalls.push_back(foo_parse_data_3);
    arrParsedataCalls.push_back(foo_parse_data_4);

    for(int i=0; i<4; ++i) {
        arrNetworkCalls[i](i);
        arrParsedataCalls[i](std::to_string(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```